# Remove space in tab panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been trying to solve this puzzle for last week and nothing works. I tried to reduce the extra space in tab panels using inspect element but it is not working. Any direction would be really appreciated for this UI level change.

Here is the link.
http://ec2-52-77-213-236.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

I want to remove this unused space after return time and so on in other types of trips as well.

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  If the button moves to the left, then there's a big white space to the right of it.  Do you want that whole bar shortened (horizontally)?  **Also** - good questions have the code *in the question*.  Your question will be **worthless** to future visitors as it stand, because once the issue is fixed, your link does not represent the problem.

Comment: I have removed my answer as it got downvoted. You have to explain what do you mean by "remove spaces"

Comment: I just want to remove this extra space and all other items to use this extra space. would it be good for UI perspective ?

Comment: @Alon I also jsut understood the question
next to Return Date And Time input box, to right there is a white space 
Return Date And Time ------ Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.round-trip .form-control {
border-radius: 0;
box-shadow: none;
height: 55px;
border: none;
width: 205px;//<=======
border-right: 1px #ddd solid;
}
```

for this block

```
<input required="" type="text" class="form-control start_date" id="datetimepicker1" value="" placeholder="Return Date and Time" name="end">
```

Comment: + you earned the best marketing campain :D

Comment: I am just a backend dev sir.. no need to market anything :)

Comment: I am kidding, I just wanted to tell you that others might have this perception. But as per the solution I gave, in your theme.css line 52 you find this mistake. reducing the width to 205px will solve it

Comment: i reduced the width to  205px and it shortened the width more and as a result the extra blank space increased.

Comment: Increase the width or just removed it from the css file:) I just understood your question.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to overwrite bootstrap.css

.tab-content > .active {display: inline-block;}

Comment: This is reducing the width of whole panel and it shrinks to left which is not looking good. thanks for your answer !! it solved my problem but it created another one as well :) could you please help to suggest more over this design.

Comment: not sure why you are downvoting this... it removes the whitespace as you asked. If you need the other elements to fill that extra whitespace, then that too can be solved with css